# Как получить ID элемента в recyclerView , Database Firebase android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-database

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно получить ID элемента , затем же его вставить в  Sqlite. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: На схеме нет ни одного id. Откуда его нужно получить? Из firebase - тогда в чем проблема сделать это как в документации, из recyclerView - тогда причем здесь firebase?

Comment: а вот где цифры 1,2,3 это не ID. Их нельзя как id взять?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно копировать id элемента в структуру документа:

```
Shops:  
    1:  
       id : "1"   
       cost : 10  
       name : "Milk"  
   2:  
       id : "2" 
       cost : 150
       name : "...."
   ....
```

В java необходимо создать модель:

```
class Shop{
   public String id;
   public float cost;//или другой тип
   public String name;

   public Shop{}

   //....
}
```

Затем считать данные как написано в документации(гайде):
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Что бы получить id из RecyclerView - нужно определить onClick:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick

Firebase database - может хранить данные офлайн и нет необходимости в Sqlite:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities

Comment: у меня настолько много элементов около 2к , придется в каждом добавлять id? есть другой способ. Sqlite мне нужен для создания списка избранных.Просто если сделать список избранных в Firebase, То у всех пользователей будет одинаковый список избранных, потому что у меня нет регистрации.

Comment: Я ничего не нашел по поводу извлечения id, Но если твои id выглядят как 1,2..х - то это не проблема их добавить..В firebase есть анонимная авторизация - так что можно так сделать список избранных. Вообще ситуация интересная! Попробуй описать ситуацию на англоязычной ветке, там сидят разработчики firebase - они точно скажут можно что-то сделать или нет.

Comment: хорошо , спасибо вам большое за помощь.